# How to find number of unique elements in each row of a matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix, unique

I'm trying to implement some sort of interpolation algorithm. `I` is an N*4 matrix, holding indices of surrounding points of `N` other points. But elements in each row of `I` may not be unique, meaning two or more of them may refer to an individual point. I want to know how many unique indices are available in each row, and I want to do it as fast as possible since `N` is big!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, [Mohsen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36970914/2093077) is a general solution for this problem, but `arrayfun` was too slow for me. So I thought a little more about it and found a much faster solution. 
I compare all pairs of columns and increase a counter if they were equal:

```
tic;
S = zeros(N, 1, 'uint32');
Nu = S+4; % in my case most of point are surrounded by four different points
for i=1:3
    for j=(i+1):4
        S = S + uint32(I(:, i)==I(:, j));
    end
end
% Nu(S==0) = 4;
Nu(S==1) = 3;
Nu((S==2)|(S==3)) = 2; % why? :)
Nu(S==6) = 1;
toc;
```

For `N=189225`, `arrayfun` takes 14.73s on my PC but summation takes only 0.04s.

**Edit: Take care of different numbers of columns**

Here's a modification of the code above. Now we can also have the places of unique values in each row! This one hasn't the `:)` problem and can be used for higher numbers of columns. Still taking 0.04s on my PC for 189225 rows.

```
tic;
uniq = true(N, 4);
for i=1:3
    for j=(i+1):4
          uniq(I(:, i)==I(:, j), j) = false;
    end
end
Nu = sum(uniq, 2);
toc;
```

**Edit(2): Comparison with [EBH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2627163/ebh)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45470497/2093077)**

After a while I needed this for another problem where I wanted number of unique elements in each row of matrices with different numbers of columns. So I compared my code with EBH's to see if their code is faster. I ran both codes on matrices with rows from 10K to 100K, and columns from 6 to 60. The results are average of spent time (in seconds) of 3 different runs:

[image]

I'm testing this in 2016a and there has been a significant improvement in performance of for-loops in latest versions of MATLAB. So you may need to to compare it yourself if you want to run it in older versions.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `unique` function on each row and count the elements of the result:

```
arrayfun(@(x) numel(unique(I(x,:))), (1:size(I,1)).')
```

The index array is transposed so that the result is a column vector.

Comment: Would you please check my answer. mamnoon misham ;)

Comment: how does one edit the above syntax so that it does not account for zeros as an unique element?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a super fast way to do that without loops:

```
accumarray(repmat(1:size(I,1),1,size(I,2)).',I(:),[],@(x) numel(unique(x)))
```

This will give you a vector size N, where the element in place k is the number of unique elements in `I(k,:)`.